# Generate select option entries from variables in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, redux-saga

I am still not as fluent in ReactJS, [Ant Design](https://2x.ant.design/), Sagas and Reducers as I thought I am: **I am trying to maintain/ debug a single-page app and I am not sure which files I have to adjust and how.**

The goal is to add the following `<select>` in their `render()` function within `component.tsx`:

```js
<Select showSearch
        style={{ width: 150 }}
        placeholder="Select entity" 
        // onChange={(e) => { this.handleSelectorChange("Entity", e) }} // to tackle later
        // value={this.props.selectedEntity.toString()}                 // ------ " ------
>
<Option value="0">Option 0</Option>
   {this.props.availableEntities.map((myEntity) =>
    (<Option key={myEntity.Id.toString()}
             value={myEntity.Id.toString()}>{myEntity.Name}</Option>))}
</Select>
```

In the respective `container.tsx`, I added:

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state ) => ({
    availableEntities: GeneralSelectors.getAvailableEntities(state),
});
```

What I get back is the following is only `Option 0` instead of all entities (and even on a wrong place), see screenshot

[image: Screenshot of select options]

**How do I get my selection options dynamically generated using data from an API?** Since I do not see backend being called (using the *Network* tab of my Chrome debugger), I assume something is wrong with the sagas, but that is just an hypothesis.

#### Background info

For another single-page-app (SPA) of the same project which already has that `<select>` inside, I found a `urls.ts` which looks as follows

```js
import UrlMap from "../UrlMap"
import * as Actions from "./actions"
import * as GeneralActions from "../general/actions"

export const urls = [
    new UrlMap("myWorkingSPA",
        () => [
            Actions.load(),
            GeneralActions.loadEntities(),
            Actions.loadDifferencePositions()
        ])
];
```

I don't know where this file is actually called, and what I have to modify where in order to include it.

In the respective `actions.ts` of the running SPA I find

```
export function loadEntities() : Action {
    return {
        type: LOAD_ENTITIES
    }
}
```

I am not sure whether my SPA is also taking this `actions.ts` or not.

The `sagas.ts` is the same for the running SPA and for my component:

```
function* loadEntities() {
    const url = config.apiBaseUrl + "/api/Entities";

    try {
        const response: Response = yield fetch(url);
        const json: Interfaces.Entity[] = yield response.json();
        yield put(Actions.setEntities(json));
    } catch (e) {
        notification.error({ message: "Error", description: "Error loading Entities" });
    }
}

function* watchLoadEntities() {
    yield takeEvery(Actions.LOAD_ENTITIES, loadEntities);
}
```

Hope that was not too much information, but I guess it is all related to the problem.

#### References

- [populate select option in reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57043036/populate-select-option-in-reactjs)
- [Mapping checkboxes inside checkboxes ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55131710/mapping-checkboxes-inside-checkboxes-reactjs)

Comment: "I assume something is wrong with the sagas, but that is just an hypothesis." I'd say that this might be a correct hypothesis. This selector `GeneralSelectors.getAvailableEntities(state)` should create the slice of the store you need to populate your `<Select />`. If you track it down, you might find the correct actions that should be dispatched to get your info. As for the other `<Select />` component, is the call made during the application startup? When a specific component mounts? Finding _when_ the call is actually made might help you.

Comment: @Clafou: I wrote an answer instead. Feel free to comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I also found another `sagas.ts` which was also in effect:

```js
function* parseUrl({ payload }) {
    const pathName = payload.location.pathname;

    const myComponentURI: match<{}> = matchPath(pathName, { path: config.uiBaseUrl + "myComponent" });
    if (myComponentURI) {
        yield put(GeneralActions.loadEntities()); // <---
    }

   // ... here are many more const. for various different pages
}
```

The `GeneralActions` refers to an `actions.ts` in a directory `general`.

I solved the issue by putting the marked line. **Warning:** I believe, this is not the way things should be implemented, I am just saying that it hot-fixed my issue.

As [clafou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4211681/clafou) pointed out in a comment, the clean way would be to trigger the `yield` on startup.

Comment: I don't really know the way your application works so it might totally be correct to do it that way. Using a saga to dispatch some actions in response to another action seems completely normal to me (disclaimer : I'm not a redux-saga expert). Glad you could find a solution to your issue! :)